# Cocos2d: How to create a global timer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm doing a cocos2d project which I'm completely newbie in. So please bear with me.

When creating a timer in the game that will be use throughout the app.

```
-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    [self.timerCountDown invalidate];


        self.timerCountDown = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerCountDown:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void) timerCountDown: (NSTimer*) timer {

    self.secondsLeft--;

}
```

Apparently when I click the game to go to another view, the onEnter got called again that triggers the timer to count again.

So my question is how should I approach this problem to make the timer continues the same counts even I'm in a different views for like 2 mins.

If it is purely iOS app, I thought about 2 options. First one is pass through segue and second one is to use UserDefaults.

However I don't think it is the same for cocos2d. There is no segue as well!

Any advice will be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: you need to use a singleton class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29287968/calculate-the-time-between-the-switches-of-a-view-controller-and-another-view-co/29288656#29288656

Comment: is that the only way? I thought about that too. Can you use background threads instead?

Comment: no it is not the only way, though I thought I would approach your problem this way, you may wanna wait for other comments/answers if you think singleton is not the best approach for this.

Comment: @tipsywacky bad idea with cocos2d, it lives on the main thread, and if you create/modify stuff on another thread, that will mess up the GL rendering.

Comment: @tipsywacky regarding `onEnter`, it is invoked when you add a CCNode to another. So in order to get more than one `onEnter` invocation, you are removing this object from its parent, keeping it somewhere, and adding it later to an other node. Tricky at best, there could be lots of surprises in doing that with action sequences, animations, particle systems.

Comment: Yeah, this is the thing. When transitioning to another scene. onEnter is invoked again, which resets the timer.  What can I do to make a proper transition without reseting the timer?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `NSTimer`.  Instead use the delta times passed to the `update:` method.

```
@interface YourClass ()
{
    CGFloat _timeout;
}
@end

@implementation YourClass

-(void)onEnter
{
    [super onEnter];
    _timeout = 30.0;
}

- (void)update:(CCTime)deltaTime
{
    _timeout -= deltaTime;
    if (_timeout < 0.0) {
        // Do thing
        _timeout = 30.0;
    }
}
```

That is a repeating timeout; you'll need another variable for a single-shot timeout.

Comment: Alright let me try this method.  It's kinda clean this way. One more thing though. Why do you guys use interface {  CGFloat _timeout; } instead of declaring a property?

Comment: Keeps it completely private making it harder for classes outside the implementation to touch the value.

Comment: Okay so there is no preference to it lol. Because I was mostly trained to use property in native apps. And I see alot of cocos2d examples use local variables instead.

Comment: You can use properties; this is lighter weight as a setter/getter method is not used.  Do whatever you feel happiest with.

Comment: Very unfortunate. This method resets the timer on my side. :( thanks for your help though.

Comment: It resets the timer when?  Sounds like you just need to find the right method to set the initial value.